# Не работает система сеток в теге <footer>

Tags: bootstrap

В теге header все работает, но если сделать в футере, то logo и society вылезают за сетку

```
 <footer class="footer">
        <div class="container" style="background: url('../img/header.png');">
                <div class="row justify-content-around" >
                <div class="col-md-4" style="">logo</div>
                <div class="col-md-4" style="">society</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все работает и ничего не вылазит:

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" >

  <footer class="footer">
    <div class="container" style="background: url('https://image.freepik.com/free-vector/coloured-summer-background_1048-2276.jpg');">
      <div class="row justify-content-around" >
        <div class="col-md-4" style="">logo</div>
        <div class="col-md-4" style="">society</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
```

Comment: Благодарю, не заметил)